# OpenCV Java [ WARN:2] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072875772

Tags: java, opencv, javafx

I have been trying to make a simple application that opens and closes the camera. So far, the opening part works, but every time I try to close the camera, this series of events happen:

1. The capture stops capturing, but the lights still on and the image does not get cleared.
2. The second time i press the stop button, the image gets cleared.
3. After that, whenever i press the start button, regardless on whether or not I did step 2, it does nothing and gives me this error:

> [ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status:
>   -1072875772 [ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072875772 [ WARN:2] videoio(MSMF): can't grab
>   frame. Error: -1072875772

```
package application;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class FXHelloCVController {

@FXML
private AnchorPane MainPane;

@FXML
private Button StartButton;

@FXML
private ImageView currentFrame;

@FXML
private Button StopButton;

private ScheduledExecutorService timer;
private VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(); 
private boolean cameraActive = false;
private static int cameraID = 0;

@FXML
void startCamera(ActionEvent event) {
    if(!this.cameraActive) {
        //if the camera is not active, open the camera

        cameraActive = true;

        this.capture.open(cameraID);

        if(this.capture.isOpened()) {
            //if the stream is available, run at 30fps (33 ms)

            Runnable frameGrabber = new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Image imageToShow = grabFrame();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() { 
                        currentFrame.setImage(imageToShow); }
                    });
                }


            };

            this.timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 33, 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

    }

}

private Image grabFrame() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();

    // check if the capture is open
    if (this.capture.isOpened()){
        try{
            // read the current frame
            this.capture.read(frame);

            // if the frame is not empty, process it
            if (!frame.empty()){

                Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", frame, buffer);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            // log the error
            System.err.println("Exception during the image elaboration: " + 
e);
        }
    }

    return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
}

@FXML
private void stopCamera(){
    cameraActive = false;
    if (this.timer!=null && !this.timer.isShutdown()){
        try{
            // stop the timer
            this.timer.awaitTermination(33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            this.timer.shutdown();
            this.currentFrame.setImage(null);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This right here is my controller object, can anyone help me find out whats wrong?

Comment: Hi,did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same error because of a hardware failure. I am on Windows, and it stopped working after an update. Could be a driver issue also. I strongly suspect it originated from the platform level. 
I changed my webcam, and it was all well again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your stopCamera method needs capture.release().

Probably unrelated but I think the timer stuff is the wrong way to go.  Even if the camera is set to 30 FPS, skew between its streaming clock and your Java timing will eventually cause a breakdown.  Use an infinite loop in a thread instead and know that capture.read() will suspend until a frame is available.  The infinite loop will work correctly at any FPS, provided you have enough processing power to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't even start the camera. It was because 'Kaspersky Endpoint Security', after exiting the virus guard it started working.